# List of BUKRS which the current user is allowed to see

Tags: abap, opensql

Is there a way to get a list of all BUKRS which the current user is allowed to see?

I want to use this list as a filter in open sql. Imagine the result of the method I search stored the result in `bk_list`. Then I could use `bk_list` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE bukrs IN bk_list
```

Comment: If CDS is an alternative, there are built-in authorizations. Otherwise you need to know the authorization object (there is one for every SAP ERP module) and build the list yourself by using `AUTHORITY-CHECK`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way to do it, based on the class `CL_AUTH_OBJECTS_TO_SQL` (officially supported, as of ABAP 7.50, as explained in the documentation of [AUTHORITY-CHECK](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapauthority-check.htm)), here the program reads the flights from the read-authorized airline carriers :

```
DATA(authsql) = cl_auth_objects_to_sql=>create_for_open_sql( ).

authsql->add_authorization_object( EXPORTING
    iv_authorization_object = 'S_CARRID'
    it_activities = VALUE #( ( auth_field = 'ACTVT' value = '03' ) )
    it_field_mapping = VALUE #(
      ( auth_field = 'CARRID'
        view_field = VALUE #( table_ddic_name = 'SFLIGHT' field_name = 'CARRID' ) ) ) ).

DATA(where) = authsql->get_sql_condition( ).

SELECT * FROM sflight INTO TABLE @data(sflights) WHERE (where).
```

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid you can do it one by one only. Roughly:

```
SELECT bukrs
       INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_t001)
       FROM t001
       WHERE ... . "Selection critera, if necessary

LOOP AT lt_t001
     ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_t001>).
  DATA(lv_tabix) = sy-tabix.
  AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT 'F_BKPF_BUK'
           ID 'BUKRS' FIELD <ls_t001>-bukrs
           ID 'ACTVT' FIELD '03'. "Here you need the proper activity (display '03' /change '02' / etc.)
  IF sy-subrc <> 0. "Auth check failed
    DELETE lt_t001 INDEX lv_tabix.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

At the end lt_t001 contains only the company codes, for which the user has authorization.

Comment: OK, this should work. If I understand this correctly, then you check every BUKR, if AUTHORITY-CHECK is successful, then add the BKUR to the list of allowed BUKRS. It is a bit like "brute force attack", but it works. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: It is the other way around: first all company codes are selected and then autorization is checked for each of them. If auth check fails, company code is removed from the list. On the other hand, yes it is brute force, but as far as I know, authorization can only be checked for single values and not for ranges/mass values.