# AUTHORITY-CHECK for complex selection field (like SELECT-OPTIONS)

Tags: abap

I have a custom report with the following selection screen. It allows the user to input value ranges when executing the report.

[image]

I want to carryout an authorization check to the inputs that the user has entered.

For this I use `AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT` with the user and the selection field;

```
  AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT 'P_PYEVDOC'
  FOR USER sy-uname
  ID 'BUKRS' FIELD pnpbukrs-low
  .
```

Where **pnpbukrs** is the selection field that the user has entered.

How do I do this check properly for all possible combinations that the user might give?

When I provide the direct **pnpbukrs** field, the Options in the selection field is considered in the auth. check giving errors.

When I user **pnpbukrs-low**, only a single value is used in the auth. check making a check bypass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case the selection table contains generic entries, intervals, excluded entries or excluded intervals, you should first get the list of companies corresponding to the selection table (with `WHERE ... IN selectiontable` ; `IN` will deal with all these kinds of filters), then do an authority-check on each of the real companies.

For instance, I assume that the companies are to be taken from the table `T001` :

```
SELECT bukrs FROM t001 WHERE bukrs IN pnpbukrs INTO TABLE @DATA(companies).

LOOP AT companies ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<company>).
  AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT 'P_PYEVDOC'
                ID 'BUKRS' FIELD <company>.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    " this company is not authorized, do something
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

PS #1: If the goal is only to select the authorized data from a given table, you may use [the class `CL_AUTH_OBJECTS_TO_SQL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375514/list-of-bukrs-which-the-current-user-is-allowed-to-see) (>= 7.50)

PS #2: for `AUTHORITY-CHECK`, it's useless to mention `FOR USER sy-uname` as it's the default setting.

Comment: How can excluded intervals be checked in this instance? Like company codes other than given range.

Comment: @Isuru while select with `bukrs IN pnpbukrs`, it has already filtered base on range table `pnpbukrs` so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Good one Sandra. I think the value inside the `IN` clause should be `pnpbukrs[]`, not `pnpbukrs` as it an internal table with header line.

Comment: @Binh and Sandra; this is genius, got the values and looped it into the auth. check and it works.

Comment: @Dorad, no need of adding `[]` in positions where there's no confusion possible: behind `IN` only a selection table is allowed so the syntax checker/compiler will ignore the header line (it's only needed in positions like parameters, CLEAR, ...)

Answer (score 4):

**For range with any data**

Go for [@Sandra Rossi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54978711/1157173)

**For range filled with `LOW` component only:**

Try looping over the select-options field and make an authority check for each iteration:

```
LOOP AT pnpbukrs ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line>).
    AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT 'P_PYEVDOC'
                    FOR USER sy-uname
                    ID 'BUKRS'
                    FIELD <line>-low.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: looping in the LOW will not work as the fields in the HIGH and ranges will not be checked.

Comment: @Isuru You can add one more line to check HIGH value

Comment: @Binh can ranges also be checked in this case, like a value range from 2000 to 3000?